# cannot resolve symbol 'tag'

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in learning android java. I learning the java android tutorial from Youtube and I follow exactly the coding from the video, but my coding showing "cannot resolve symbol 'tag' " on the android studio. May I know what is the problem? and hope to get explanation from all the master here.

```
package com.NewApplicationLifeCycle;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onCreate" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onStart" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onResume" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onPause" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onStop" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onRestart" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i( tag: "State", msg: "onDestroy" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to remove `tag:` and `msg:` from your `Log.i(...)` calls.

Comment: I would recommend against starting to learn with youtube tutorials. First of all, they all assume you have a certain base of knowledge already. Do you know Java, for instance? Secondly, many of them are created by people who should study it themselves, instead of creating tutorials. Thirdly, any yahoo can upload tutorial videos. When it comes to books, they are proofread by several people who know what they're doing, so at least there you're sure most if not all the obvious errors are removed before printing.

Answer (score 6):

IDEs give you more context about the parameters of the function you're calling by highlighting the parameter names. Like in this case `Log.i(tag: String, msg: String)` accepts two parameters `tag` and `msg` but you don't have to write them yourself when calling the function.

Remove `tag:` and `msg:` from `Log.i(...)` calls and call it like this:

```
Log.i( "State", "onRestart" );
```

and so on for others as well.

Comment: And this is why code should be text and not pictures.

Comment: Thank you Osama Abdul Rehman, finally i get the code run correctly at android studio

Comment: @Machine_Z No problem, Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
var tag = "your tag name"
var msg = "you message"

Log.i( tag +"State", msg+ "onCreate" );
```

otherwise :-

```
Log.d(tag, message)

Log.i( "your tag name","your message" );
```

- > and check this official [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)  
  > how can i Write and View Logs with Logcat

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the log.i method correctly.
This is how it is defined in the platform

```
 /**
 * Send an {@link #INFO} log message.
 * @param tag Used to identify the source of a log message.  It usually identifies
 *        the class or activity where the log call occurs.
 * @param msg The message you would like logged.
 */
public static int i(String tag, String msg) {
    return println(LOG_ID_MAIN, INFO, tag, msg);
}
```

meaning you need to  pass 2 string values when calling the method.
correct way to use it will be this way

```
 Log.i( "State","onStart" )
```

the tag and message will be shown automatically by  android studio you  do not need to put them since they are just an IDE feature to  make the code readable

Comment: Thank you Austin Gwa, finally i get the code run correctly at android studio.